# How to securely build a key vault with secrets with terraform

Tags: security, azure-devops, terraform

Stack: git, Azure DevOps, Terraform, Azure

I want to create and populate an azure key vault using terraform+azure devops.

**My question is this:** how do I build this key vault in terraform without storing the secrets to populate it with in plain text?

If I encrypt a file containing the secrets and check that into source control to be decrypted/used by the terraform when populating the key vault I want to create, I'd have to manually create and store a key in a separate azure key vault that I'd have to manually create.  This seems like it would be an anti-pattern if trying to keep all infrastructure as code, so I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: No this made sense, thank you for your reply!  For now, I am just creating the KV manually and work with it as a data source in the TF that way, but will be looking for a more "as code" method later on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it **outside of TF**. So either you do it manually, or use `local-exec` to run some CLI or script to create the secret values which are not going to end up in the state file.